# How to overload weak declared function of a C library using ctypes in python?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to setup a test environment to validate my C library I am working on. This library is embedded on a device running a custom linux. After some reading on the net, I decided to go with python and ctypes to call my library functions from python. It works well for almost all my functions but I get stuck when coming to the callback functions.

My callback functions are defined in the library as "weak". I would like to know if I can overload my weak C function using python ctypes ?

See what I have tried, as an example :

libtest.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libtest.h"

int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    custom_callback(a);
    return a*b;
}

int __attribute__((weak)) custom_callback(int a)
{
    printf("Callback not redefined, a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

main.py

```py
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("libtest.so")

CALLBACKFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int)

def py_callback_func(a):
    print("py redifinition", a)
    return 0


lib.custom_callback = CALLBACKFUNC(py_callback_func)

lib.multiply(c_int(5), c_int(10))
```

Then I run my main.py with python3 :

```
$ python3 main.py 
Callback not redefined, a = 5
```

I expect the output to be `py redifinition 5`

Am I making something wrong ? Or does ctypes simply cannot redefine a weak declared C function ?

Comment: Weak linking is mediated by the dynamic linker.  To the best of my knowledge, nothing that you do to the Python wrapper for your library after you instantiate it modulates dynamic linking in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a confusion: *weak* symbols are handled at ***link*** time, while you're "operating" at ***run*** time. The linker can't possibly know about your *Python* callback function. Although it's not an official source, check [[Wikipedia]: Weak symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) for more details. 
Also, [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). 
Here's a small demo.

*libtest00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int __attribute__((weak)) custom_callback(int a) {
    printf("Callback not redefined, a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}


int multiply(int a, int b) {
    custom_callback(a);
    return a * b;
}
```

*callback00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int custom_callback(int a) {
    printf("C callback redefinition, a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


DLL_NAME = "./libtest000.so"
CALLBACKFUNCTYPE = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.c_int)


def py_callback_func(a):
    print("PY callback redefinition", a)
    return 0


def main(*argv):
    dll_name = argv[0] if argv else DLL_NAME
    dll = ct.CDLL(dll_name)
    multiply = dll.multiply
    multiply.argtypes = [ct.c_int, ct.c_int]
    multiply.restype = ct.c_int
    #dll.custom_callback(3)
    #dll.custom_callback = CALLBACKFUNCTYPE(py_callback_func)
    #dll.custom_callback(3)
    res = multiply(5, 10)
    print("{:} returned {:d}".format(multiply.__name__, res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q055357490]> ~/sopr.sh
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> callback00.c  code00.py  code01.py  libtest00.c  libtest01.c
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o libtest000.so -fPIC -shared libtest00.c
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o libtest001.so -fPIC -shared libtest00.c callback00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> callback00.c  code00.py  code01.py  libtest00.c  libtest000.so  libtest001.so  libtest01.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python code00.py ./libtest000.so
> Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0] 64bit on linux
>
> Callback not redefined, a = 5
> multiply returned 50
>
> Done.
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python code00.py ./libtest001.so
> Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0] 64bit on linux
>
> C callback redefinition, a = 5
> multiply returned 50
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen, the ***__attribute__((weak))*** effect **is** visible. Also, regarding the commented code (that tries to set the *.dll* function): **it only operates at *CTypes* proxies level**, it doesn't change the *.dll* code (that would be preposterous).

Regarding your problem, there are a couple of ways for solving it. 
Here's one using a pointer that holds such a callback function. The pointer can be set from outside by a setter function (also exported).

*libtest01.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXEC_CALLBACK(X) \
    if (pCallback) { \
        pCallback(X); \
    } else { \
        fallbackCallback(X); \
    }


typedef int (*CustomCallbackPtr)(int a);

static CustomCallbackPtr pCallback = NULL;


static int fallbackCallback(int a) {
    printf("Callback not redefined, a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}


int multiply(int a, int b) {
    EXEC_CALLBACK(a);
    return a * b;
}


void setCallback(CustomCallbackPtr ptr) {
    pCallback = ptr;
}
```

*code01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


DLL_NAME = "./libtest01.so"
CALLBACKFUNCTYPE = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.c_int)


def py_callback_func(a):
    print("PY callback redefinition", a)
    return 0


def main(*argv):
    dll = ct.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    multiply = dll.multiply
    multiply.argtypes = [ct.c_int, ct.c_int]
    multiply.restype = ct.c_int
    set_callback = dll.setCallback
    set_callback.argtypes = [CALLBACKFUNCTYPE]
    multiply(5, 10)
    set_callback(CALLBACKFUNCTYPE(py_callback_func))
    multiply(5, 10)
    set_callback(ct.cast(ct.c_void_p(), CALLBACKFUNCTYPE))
    multiply(5, 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [064bit prompt]> ls  # Files from previous step
> callback00.c  code00.py  code01.py  libtest00.c  libtest000.so  libtest001.so  libtest01.c
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o libtest01.so -fPIC -shared libtest01.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> callback00.c  code00.py  code01.py  libtest00.c  libtest000.so  libtest001.so  libtest01.c  libtest01.so
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python code01.py
> Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0] 64bit on linux
>
> Callback not redefined, a = 5
> PY callback redefinition 5
> Callback not redefined, a = 5
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thanks CristiFati for your detailed and documented answer. I think I will remove the handy "weak" attribute from the lib that may cause portability issues in the future and is not so much ctypes python test oriented. Using function pointers and a setter seems to be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes, this would best fit in your scenario. `__attribute__((weak))` is a nice and powerful feature (supported by **some** compilers), but doesn't pretty much apply here.